# Maven cannot resolve classes

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, deployment, build

I have a curious problem with maven during test and deploy.

**Project structure**

src/main/java/com/../models/Employee.java

src/test/java/com/../models/EmployeeTest.java

**Employee**

```
public class Employee {
    private final String name;
    private final Dollars salary;

    public Employee(String name, Dollars salary) {
        this.name = name;
        this.salary = salary;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public Dollars getSalary() {
        return this.salary;
    }
}
```

**Dollars**

```
public class Dollars {

    private final BigDecimal value;
    public Dollars(BigDecimal value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public BigDecimal getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

**EmployeeTest**

```
public class EmployeeTest {

    @Test
    public void justASimpleTest() {
        Employee employee = new Employee("David", new Dollars(BigDecimal.valueOf(100)));
        Employee updatedEmployee = updateSalary(BigDecimal.valueOf(200)).apply(employee);

        assertEquals(BigDecimal.valueOf(200), updatedEmployee.getSalary().getValue());
    }

    private Function<Employee, Employee> updateSalary(final BigDecimal value) {
        return employee -> new Employee(employee.getName(), new Dollars(value));
    }
}
```

**The problem**

When i run "test", "verify" or "install" i get the following error:

```
cannot find symbol: class Employee
```

**ONLY IN THE FUNCTION!**

```
private Function<Employee, Employee> updateSalary(final BigDecimal value) {...}
                 ^^^^^^^^  ^^^^^^^^
```

But intelliJ can resolve references indeed i've no errors provided by IntelliJ, furthermore build via maven and test using JUnit run in IntelliJ works!

After some attempts i've noted that this problem appears when ***packaging*** is set to ***jar***, with `<packaging>pom</packaging>` all works fine.

This problem persiste though via cmd using "mvn clean install", via maven inside IntelliJ and on CI/CD(teamcity)

**POM**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <groupId>XXX</groupId>
    <artifactId>YYY</artifactId>
    <version>ZZZ</version>

    <artifactId>sample</artifactId>

    <properties>
        <junit.version>4.11</junit.version>
        <maven-compiler-plugin.version>3.8.1</maven-compiler-plugin.version>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-compiler-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                    <proc>only</proc>
                    <generatedSourcesDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/annotations
                    </generatedSourcesDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.7</version>
                <configuration>
                    <skip>true</skip>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Can someone explain me why this happens?
Thanks :)

Comment: In your local system, are you able to build using mvn clean install command ?

Comment: no, only "compile" works

Comment: As long as you have complete maven structure, you should be able to build the project using "mvn clean install" or "mvn clean package". If you post the project structure we may be able to help you.

Comment: Please share the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Updated with simple example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem!

Using `<packaging>pom</packaging>` tests are skipped this is why it works but this is not the solution!

The problem is that i'm using `<proc>only</proc>`. This property when has 'only' value means that only annotation processes will be executed, no compilation. This explain why in install phase it cannot find `Employee` class.

Further details about `proc` configuration [HERE](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html#proc)